# Background image and header alignment/margins

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a background image that fills the background of my entire webpage, using this CSS code:

```
html { 
  background: url(../images/image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The problem is that in my `<header>`, I am also using a `.container-fluid` class from bootstrap 3.3.7, and for some reason, it is not allowing my `.row` to go completely across the screen--instead, there is a bit of white space on both the left and right sides. Furthermore, when I try to align my `<header>` by applying some pixels to `margin-top`, those pixels also show up as white space.

How do I remove the white space so I can see my background image instead? I am guessing it has something to do with the margins.

EDIT: I have tried removing `<header>` and `.row` labels to ensure the problem does not stem from them, and sure enough, the white space is still there even without them.

Comment: This code isn't enough to debug your problem

Comment: Please provide working code

Comment: Maybe `body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/efcm7uun/ your problem does not appear to be replicable

Comment: It strangely went away after I attempted to replicate it in @haxxxton's JSFiddle. For some strange reason, it came back when I added a <footer> label--could this be caused by my browser? Some rendering issue?